# Facebook og:image throwing errors for byte array

Tags: javascript, facebook, image, arrays, sharing

I'm trying to let my users share things from our site, but I'm having trouble when I try to use an image from a byte array as the image.

It works fine when I use the URL for a regular image hosted on the site, but when I try to use an image stored in the database it gives me an error.

Here's an example metatag for the image when it's using the byte array:

This is an example of the javascript I'm using to share it:

FB.ui({
                method: 'send',
                link: 'http://myurl.com/Home/PageToShare',
                picture: 'http://myurl.com/Home/GetImg?ImageId=1',
                name: 'Shared Page',
                caption: '',
                description: ''
            }, function (response) { });

And this is the error message I get:

An error occurred. Please try again later.

API Error Code: 100
API Error Description: Invalid parameter
Error Message: picture URL is not properly formatted

The first time I tried going to the shared page in the Facebook Debugger it gave me a warning saying the image was too small, which was odd because the image it's getting is larger than the one I tried which is hosted in the images folder, and that one works fine.

Now when I try it in the debugger it doesn't give me any errors, but when I try to share it from my site it still throws that error.

I haven't been able to find anything about how to use byte array images for this, but I figure it must be possible.

Please help.  Thanks.